# apt-get install sound_play package failure in Debian Jessie

Tags: ros, ros-kinetic, sound-play, debian, jessie

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'd like to install sound_play package in my debian jessie arm64 board,however I couldn't install it by using "$apt-get install ros-kinetic-sound-play" because of unmet dependencies "libgstreamer-plugins-good1.0-0" ,the detail is listed as below:

```
root@linaro-alip:~/catkin_ws/src/# apt-get install ros-kinetic-sound-play
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 ros-kinetic-sound-play : Depends: libgstreamer-plugins-good1.0-0 but it is not installable
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

The linux distribution I used was Debian Jessie arm64, ros distribution was kinetic.I installed the sound_play package because I'd like to test some speech recognition and synthesis demos on my company's boards. I had installed and tested some demos on ubuntu 14.04 armhf (ros indigo) on another board,these demos mostly needed the support of the sound_play package,there were no problems on it.

I needed to run these demos on our new 64bits Debian Jessie boards.I checked the wiki and make sure ROS Kinetic supported Debian Jessie.However,the error log showed that "libgstreamer-plugins-good1.0-0" could't be installed in Debian.

In fact,I checked it in both official websites of debian and ubuntu,the package "libgstreamer-plugins-good1.0-0"  indeed didn't exist in Debian's package repository : https://packages.debian.org/search?suite=default&section=all&arch=any&searchon=names&keywords=libgstreamer-plugins-good1.0-0,while it exist in ubuntu's package repository:https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=default&section=all&arch=any&keywords=libgstreamer-plugins-good1.0-0&searchon=names

so,I have some problems:

1. How to solve the dependency problem in Debian Jessie?
2. Are there any other similar audio packages available that supported Debian?
3. Can I make a little change of the source codes to make the sound_play package support Debian?

Thanks!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/287431/apt-get-install-sound_play-package-failure-in-debian-jessie/) by [allen](https://answers.ros.org/users/34489/allen/) on ROS Answers with karma: 16 on 2018-04-04

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-04-04**:
As this pkg was specifically released for this platform, it would be good to report the installation problem you encountered. Please open an issue over at [ros-drivers/audio_common/issues](https://github.com/ros-drivers/audio_common/issues).

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-04-04**:
In the meantime you could try and see whether building it from source in a catkin workspace would work. See #q252478 for the general procedure, but realise that `rosdep` will not be able to install the `libgstreamer-plugins-good1.0-0` dependency. Whether a build will succeed will depend ..

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-04-04**:
.. on whether `libgstreamer-plugins-good1.0-0` is a hard build dependency or only provides plugins that are optional. Seeing the `plugins` in the filename seems to suggest the latter, but you never know.

**Comment by [allen](https://answers.ros.org/users/34489/allen/) on 2018-04-04**:
Thanks a lot! I built it from source by following your link,and I could run sound_play in Debian Jessie now.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-04-04**:
Please also report the issue with installation on Jessie on the issue tracker, as this is something that should be resolved. Probably a `rosdep` rule needs to be updated.

**Comment by [allen](https://answers.ros.org/users/34489/allen/) on 2018-04-04**:
I have solved this problem by following gvdhoorn'link,thanks!

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-04-04**:
I've re-opened your question and converted your answer into a comment as building from source is at best a work-around, not a solution. The pkg has been released into Kinetic for Jessie, so should install properly. Unavailable dependencies should have been caught earlier, or the pkg should ..

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-04-04**:
.. be blacklisted for arm64 jessie.

I see you've posted an issue on the `audio_common` tracker: [ros-drivers/audio_common#106](https://github.com/ros-drivers/audio_common/issues/106). Until that is resolved, this question should probably remain unanswered.

**Comment by [allen](https://answers.ros.org/users/34489/allen/) on 2018-04-04**:
I'm sorry I didn't explain it clearly just now.I tried the command "$ apt-get install ros-kinetic-sound-play" both on Debian Jessie arm64 and amd64, they showed the same problem.

**Comment by [allen](https://answers.ros.org/users/34489/allen/) on 2018-04-04**:
I solved this problem on Jessie amd64, but I couldn't verify it on my arm64 board now beacuse the rosdep failure on it...I guessed it might result from the proxy problem which was ignored by me before.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-04-04**:
Can you please only comment on your issue over at `ros-drivers/audio_common/issues` or here? Cross-posting like this is very inefficient.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I can install sound_play package by the command "$ apt-get install ros-kinetic-sound-play" in my Debian Jessie arm64 board now, it seems that the bug has been fixed.
Thanks!

---

Originally posted by [allen](https://answers.ros.org/users/34489/allen/) with karma: 16 on 2018-05-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0